# Swift: UICollectionView Paging Enabled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with 3 full-screen cells and want to know when a cell is focused full-screen upon swipe. The cellForItemAtIndexPath.isFocused method isn't working for me. Is this the correct use of isFocused method or should I do it another way?

Comment: try collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems()

Comment: Please post some relevant code highlighting the issue you are pointing at.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to check back and ended up solving the problem. Thank you all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ever, I can get from your question. I think you want to know on which page it is. So, Here is how i did it:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    for cell in colViewSol.visibleCells {
        let indexPath = colViewSol.indexPath(for: cell)
        // here add the code whatever you want to do 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to check back but ended up solving the problem. This was actually the solution. Thanks.